# FAT16 File System

Tags: filesystems, fat

I'm building a file system that resembles FAT. 
It has the following setup:

> | MBR | FAT Area | Data Area |

So if given the sector_size (the size of a sector in bytes), cluster_size(the size of the cluster in sectors), and disk_size (the size of the disk in clusters), how can I calculate the length of the FAT Area?

I know that MBR starts at cluster 0, and FAT Area starts at cluster 1. But I don't know what information I can use to calculate the length of the FAT Area.

Also, The root directory starts at the first cluster in the Data Area, so how can I calculate the length of the root directory as well?

Answer (score 0):

**This is how FAT12 (MSDOS 6.22) floppy image looks like:**

[image: FAT12 image example]

- on the top left is NC/VC style view of the root directory
- on the bottom left is decoded info
- and on the right is surface map of sectors
- the highlighted green sectors are MSODS.SYS file

**Drive geometry**

- heads - number of used surface sides
- tracks - number of tracks per head
- sectors - number of sectors per track
- cluster - size of cluster

**FAT**

- sector_size is smallest unit of the drive
- cluster_size is smallest unit of the FAT table
- so `cluster=N*sector` where `N={1,2,3,4,...}`
- the drive size is `heads*tracks*sectors*sector_size`
- now the FAT table has to cover whole area usable by DATA (the whole green/gray stuff)
- to be exact you need 1 value per cluster.
- this value is encoded info about:

  - next cluster the file is continuing
  - that this is last cluster of the file
  - that cluster is reserved for system,free,bad,unformated,etc...
- so first you need to decide how many bits you want to use per each value
- for example 8-bit value limits you to cca 250 clusters per drive
- that is not too much ...
- this is limiting max number of files also and space wasting due to cluster size
- some systems like FAT do not include whole drive area (just the data area)
- so only the area between first and last logical cluster/sector is stored inside FAT
- that saves up a bit space and frees more cluster indexes for DATA

**FAT size**

- FAT can be of fixed size (like FAT12,MDOS,etc)

  - so FAT table should cover all possible entries which is 2^FAT_entry_bits
  - for 12bit FAT12 it is 2^12=4096 entries
  - to single sector fits `floor(512*8/12)=341` entries
  - so for yor FAT you need `ceil(4096/341)=12` sectors
- or variable

  - in that case its length should be encoded somewhere like in MBR
  - the real question is then do you know the cluster size or FAT size ?
  - so use one of following:
  - `FAT_entries=(drive_size-reserved)/cluster_size`
  - `cluster_size=(drive_size-reserved)/FAT_entries`
  - where reserved is area not included in FAT (let it be 0 for now)
  - now let the FAT entry to be `16bit` (2Byte)
  - and have a drive of size `2heads*1024tracks*64sectprs*512Byte=64MByte`
  - and want to have `cluster_size=4096Byte`
  - so `FAT_entries=64*1024*1024/4096=16*1024`
  - now just compute the number of sectors/clusters needed for is as in above example